# Having problem understanding following C++ code. (seekp)

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
class Test
{
    char name[10];
    int data;
    public:
        void getData()
        {
            cin>>name;
            cin>>data;
        }
        void display()
        {
            cout<<name<<data;
        }
        void modify()
        {
            cin>>name;
            cin>>data;
        }
};
int main()
{
    Test t1,t2,t3,t4;
//  remove("FileIO.dat");
    t1.getData();
    t2.getData();
    t3.getData();
    t4.getData();
    fstream fp1("FileIO.dat",ios::out|ios::app);
    fp1.write((char*)&t1,sizeof(t1));
    fp1.write((char*)&t2,sizeof(t2));
    fp1.write((char*)&t3,sizeof(t3));
    fp1.write((char*)&t4,sizeof(t4));
    fp1.close();
    fstream fp2("FileIO.dat",ios::in|ios::out);
    fp2.read((char*)&t1,sizeof(t1));
    fp2.read((char*)&t2,sizeof(t2));
    int pos=-1*sizeof(t2); // ****** not understanding this line
    cout<<pos;
    fp2.seekp(pos,ios::cur);
    t2.modify();
    fp2.write((char*)&t2,sizeof(t2));
    fp2.read((char*)&t3,sizeof(t3));
    fp2.read((char*)&t4,sizeof(t4));
    t1.display();
    t2.display();
    t3.display();
    t4.display();
    fp2.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The program is written in turbo C++ and it deals with writing objects into the files and reading them back as well as updating the object that have been written into the file.

In the above code i am not understanding why -1 is multiplied by sizeof object to get the position. 
Anyone please explain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its because your program is reading the data from t1, reading the data from t2, modifying t2, and then writing *over* the contents of t2.

When the fp2 is first opened, the file looks like this (`^` represents the current position of the file pointer):

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  t1 data  |  t2 data  |  t3 data  |  t4 data  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
^
|
```

After reading t1 and t2, the pointer is now going to be pointing to the beginning of t3:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  t1 data  |  t2 data  |  t3 data  |  t4 data  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
                        ^
                        |
```

Now, in order to write *over* t2's data, we need to move the file pointer back to the start of t2. How far back is that? `-1 * sizeof(t2)`:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  t1 data  |  t2 data  |  t3 data  |  t4 data  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
                        ^
                        |
            <-----------+
                  |
                  This distance == sizeof(t2)
```

From there, your program runs `fp2.seekp(pos,ios::cur);`. Since pos is negative, it moves the file pointer backwards, and your file is left in this state:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  t1 data  |  t2 data  |  t3 data  |  t4 data  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
            ^
            |
```

And now you can overwrite t2's data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making myself clear.Clearly understood the concept... :-)

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya, ASCII art is the solution to all of the worlds problems :)